# Pb in using nedflush for memory leaks

Tags: c, nedmalloc

I try to use the debug functionalities of nedmalloc to find potential memory leaks in my code. So I activate the flags `ENABLE_LOGGING` and `NEDMALLOC_TESTLOGENTRY`.

in my program, I only use the system memory pool. At the very end of my program, I call the function `neddestroysyspool` in order to flush all memory events.

First of all, I don't manage to activate the stack trace functionality. When I change this depth, the program crashes after a few allocations. In order to compile Under VS2010, I had to define `DeinitSym` myself with a call to `CloseHandle`; I hope I'm doing right ... but it does not work properly. So I don't use it.

So I just parse the file nedmalloc.csv: I sort it thanks to addresses, sum allocated sizes and substract freed ones wrt the address. For an unknown reason, for several big chunks (size>400kb), the size given at allocation is right but the size given at free is different, above the allocated size. For example, I allocated a block of 840352 bytes, but when freed, the recorded size was 851932 bytes. Is is normal?

Does anyone has some answer(s) or hint(s) for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I really wouldn't use nedmalloc's logging facilities for memory leak detection. valgrind is a vastly superior way of finding resource leaks. I even have a hack there in nedmalloc to have it use the system allocator instead of dlmalloc precisely in order to avail of valgrind.

Secondly, yes the stack backtracing code can be a little brittle. If I remember rightly I did something naughty to get the performance considerably higher at the expense of it not quite working well. I'll be blunt in saying almost no one but me ever used that code path, so I never had much reason to debug it properly. It worked well enough for my purposes.

Thirdly for larger blocks, dlmalloc will round up allocations including their bookkeeping to a 64Kb multiple, so it is expected that a 12 chunk allocation would be turned into a 13 chunk allocation.

Lastly, I as the author of nedmalloc would recommend you not use nedmalloc on Windows 7 or better, or any Linux with a 3.x kernel, or any Mac OS X produced in the past three years. Why? The system allocator is probably good enough and as I personally haven't needed nedmalloc for some years, I'll freely admit the code is bit rotting.

Hope that helps.

Niall

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I cannot use valgrind as we are working on VS2010 :(. I choose nedmalloc because it is almost the only memory allocator I have found which is thread safe, scalable, has some debug functionalities, is quite competitive with current allocators, and is under LGPL-like licence. I just wanted to use all the debug functionalities ... too bad, but I will code a little workaround for the pb of the backtrace. Also I understand the chunk size problem, it makes sense. Again, thank you !

Comment: I remember reading recently that Google's very good Dr. Memory memory leak tool gained Visual Studio support - see http://code.google.com/p/drmemory/. Microsoft provides a dtrace style memory logger in the Windows kernel called UMDH (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343). Lastly, there is an ancient Visual Studio plugin called Visual Leak Detector which may or may not still work in modern Visual Studios. Good luck! Niall

Comment: I tried once Dr. Memory... not convincing, but it was a couple of years ago. I must try again; and I will glance at UMDH, looks promising. Thanks for all!